# Linear Algebra - Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do you find the dimension of the following vector space?
$$
{A \in M_{22}: A \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 2&4
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0 \\ 0&0
\end{bmatrix}
}
$$

The answer is 2, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write $$A =\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c&d
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the conditions $a+2b = 0$ and $2a+4b=0$ can be replaced by the single condition $a+2b=0$. Since this also holds for the two other equations, the dimension of the linear space is equal to the dimension of the subspace $(a,b,c,d)$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $a+2b = 0$ and $c+2d= 0$.
To put this in another way: it is the kernel of the following linear transformation:
$$f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2:(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (a+2b,c+2d)$$
Which is obviously surjective so the dimension of the kernel is $2$ by the rank-nullity theorem.